# Generic email validator

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I want to create a form where the user will enter his email. I'd like to validate email format client-side.

Is there any generic email validator in Angular 2?

NB: Something similar to [AngularJS validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use Form Directives and Control to do this.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
     myForm: ControlGroup;
     mailAddress: Control;

     constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
         this.mailAddress = new Control(
            "",
            Validators.compose([Validators.required, GlobalValidator.mailFormat])
        );
     }

     this.addPostForm = builder.group({
            mailAddress: this.mailAddress
     });
}
```

Import:

```
import { FormBuilder, Validators, Control, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
```

Then your `GlobalValidator` class:

```
export class GlobalValidator {

    static mailFormat(control: Control): ValidationResult {

        var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;

        if (control.value != "" && (control.value.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value))) {
            return { "incorrectMailFormat": true };
        }

        return null;
    }  
}

interface ValidationResult {
    [key: string]: boolean;
}
```

And then your HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="mailAddress" class="req">Email</label>
    <input type="text" ngControl="mailAddress" />
    <div *ngIf="mailAddress.dirty && !mailAddress.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <p *ngIf="mailAddress.errors.required">mailAddressis required.</p>
        <p *ngIf="mailAddress.errors.incorrectMailFormat">Email format is invalid.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more information about this, you can read this good article : https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-form-validation-9b26f73fcb81#.jrdhqsnpg or see this github project for a [working example](https://github.com/AdrienTorris/AspNet5Angular2Playground).

(edit : that reg ex does not seem to check for a dot in the domain

I use this one instead

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

cfr http://emailregex.com/

Comment: One of the limitations of this is Angular2 doesn't still allows http requests in asynchrone validators. This issue is still open on github : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1068#issuecomment-183766054

Comment: ATTENTION!!! Here the regular expression EMAIL_REGEXP is not properly constructed and it shows this mail as valid: "asd@f"

Comment: @JustShadow technically that email address IS valid. The limitation to 5+ characters however is not coherent with this regex.

Comment: what's used in angular 2.4.1 for Control?

Comment: i could just add `email` to my input if i wouldn't  care for `xxx@gmail` without `.com` being invalid

Answer (score 77):

You can do only using html:

```
<md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Email</label>
        <input md-input
            id="contact-email"
            type="text"
            ngControl="email"
            #email="ngForm"
            [(ngModel)]="contact.email"
            required
            pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,6})+$">

    <div class="md-errors-spacer" [hidden]="email.valid || email.untouched">
        <div class="md-char-counter" *ngIf="email.errors && email.errors.required">
            Email is required
        </div>
        <div class="md-char-counter" *ngIf="email.errors && email.errors.pattern">
            Email is invalid
        </div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: I much prefer this approach to using a code based solution... thanks!

Comment: FWIW, with new domain endings like .google, .bike. and many others the email validation pattern needs to be adjusted.
This might be helpful:
http://emailregex.com/
For JavaScript in HTML5 this is the pattern:
```pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$"```

Comment: The pattern that worked for me was:

pattern="^(\\w|[0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_\\`{|}~-])+@(\\w|[0-9-])+(?:[.](\\w|[0-9-])+)*$" notice that the double-backslashes. The pattern failed to work with only one backslash before each 'w'. The reason could be that this string lives inside the pattern property of @Component. Not sure though.

Comment: Trying to write RFC-compliant regular expressions for email can be insanely convoluted.  People have been debating about this for years.  I would suggest that the best regex would be one that checks for something before the @ symbol followed by something after it with a dot.   Then follow up by sending an email verification to the address.  This looks like:  pattern=".+@.+\..+"

Comment: my browser freezes when typing long emails, using this approach. The problem might be in regex itself.

Comment: `<ion-input type="email"
                   [(ngModel)]="account.email"
                   name="email"
                   required
                   #name="ngModel"
                   pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\‌​.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$">

        </ion-input>`

not working :( i don't know why

Answer (score 65):

**For angular 4 and above:**

According to **[This](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/d69717c)** you can use "email validator".

Example:

If you use template-driven forms:

```
<input type="email" name="email" email>
<input type="email" name="email" email="true">
<input type="email" name="email" [email]="true">
```

If you use model-driven forms(aka ReactiveFormsModule) use **Validators.email**:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
    email: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.email]],
});
```

---

Old answer: You can use angular 2 **FormGroup**,

By using validators.pattern and regex like this:

```
 let emailRegex = '^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$';
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
        email: ['', [<any>Validators.required,  <any>Validators.pattern(emailRegex) ]],
 });
```

Comment: not work ,always return false(but actually true when I run pattern.test('xxx'))

Comment: @Daniel.Woo Maybe you can change the email regex to solve this problem?

Comment: This seems to me the best answer. Using Validators.pattern is the best approach. Also the regex seems perfect. I have tried all the regex here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript but they don't really work for me. Just the regex in this answer works for me.

Comment: This is the easiest method of email validation. You can wrap Validators.pattern(regexp) in a method call and then you end up with a custom validator. No point in reinventing the wheel every time.

Comment: it's allowed, if am enter this format `ram.ram@ra`. it means it will be accept without dot (.) on the Email ID.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way of validating a field using RegEx. You can bind a method to the keyUp event of the field.

In your component:

```
import {NgForm} from 'angular2/common';

//...

emailValidator(email:string): boolean {
    var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (!EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

In your HTML (view)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.email"
           placeholder="Email address" required ngControl="email"
           #email="ngForm"
           (keyup)="emailValidator(email.value) == false ? emailValid = false : emailValid = true">
    <div [hidden]="emailValid || email.pristine" class="alert alert-sm alert-danger">Email address is invalid</div>
</div>
```

Another option (required field + validate when user leaves the field)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="registerEmail">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.email"
           placeholder="Email address" required ngControl="email"
           #email="ngForm"
           (blur)="emailValidator(email.value) == true ? emailIsInvalid = false : emailIsInvalid = true">
    <div [hidden]="email.valid || email.pristine" class="alert alert-sm alert-danger">This field is required</div>
    <div [hidden]="!emailIsInvalid" class="alert alert-sm alert-danger">Email address is invalid</div>
</div>
```

This method will work with any validation, so you could change the RegEx and validate Credit Card, Date, Time etc...

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way to do this is using a custom directive. I like this approach as it's more consistent with the other ng2 validators.

```
import { Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validator, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Directive({
    selector: '[validateEmail][formControlName], [validateEmail][formControl],[validateEmail][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => EmailValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class EmailValidator implements Validator {

    constructor() {
    }

    validate(c: AbstractControl) {
        let EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;

        return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(c.value) ? null : {
            validateEmail: {
                valid: false
            }
        };


    }}
```

Then usage in html is

```
<input class="form-control" 
               type="email"
               [(ngModel)]="user.emailAddress" 
               name="emailAddress" 
               placeholder="first.last@example.com"
               validateEmail
```

Comment: it's allowed, if am enter this format `ram.ram@ra`. it means it will be accept without dot (.) on the Email ID.

Comment: similar to https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html for anyone is searching for a full code example... and this one is good because it's inline on the html tag

Answer (score 4):

I guess just now there is no email validator, but it's pretty easy to add a custom one. See this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mH91OzYRa4hYAtHBWL5m?p=preview) I used the same regex as angular1 uses.

```js
function emailValidator(control) {
  var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;

  if (!EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value)) {
    return {invalidEmail: true};
  }
}
```

Comment: ATTENTION!!! Here the regular expression EMAIL_REGEXP is not properly constructed and it shows this mail as valid: "asd@f"

Comment: In fact `asd@f` is a valid email address following RFC 821 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc821)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [ng2-validation-manager](https://github.com/sabrio/ng2-validation-manager) for reactive forms which makes validation match easier:

```
this.form = new ValidationManager({
  'email'       : 'required|email',
  'password'    : 'required|rangeLength:8,50'
});
```

and the view:

```
<form [formGroup]="form.getForm()" (ngSubmit)="save()">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
      <div *ngIf="form.hasError('email')" class="alert alert-danger">
        {{form.getError('email')}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
      <div *ngIf="form.hasError('password')" class="alert alert-danger">
        {{form.getError('password')}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update For Angular 4**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.user = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormGroup({
            firstName: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
            lastName: new FormControl('')
        }),
        age: new FormControl('',null,validate),
        email: new FormControl('',emailValidator),
    // ...
    });
}
```

Validator

```
export function emailValidator(control: AbstractControl):{[key: string]: boolean} {
    var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (control.value != "" && (control.value.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value))) {
        return {invalid:true};
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span *ngIf="user.get('email').touched && !user.get('email').valid && !user.get('email').pristine">
            <small>Invalid email</small>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in Angular form validators without a form. I'm not sure if it's good practice, but it works.

```
const control = new FormControl('', Validators.email);
control.setValue(valueToCheck);
console.log(control.errors);
```

Other answers have already shown how to use it in a form:

```
this.contactUsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),          
      emailAddress: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      message: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think nowadays you can use browser validation here. Email fields has a decent support and you can get validation result from `element.validity.valid`. You just need to pass this through the Angular custom validator

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState and http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-email-tel-url for details

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example?  Also, this will will only work with Web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-validation

**npm install ng2-validation --save  ng2-validation**

I'm not responding exaclty your question but for a lot of common scenarios you can find a custom validator  already implemented

example in your case : 
email : ['', [CustomValidators.email]]

Best Reagards,