# Regular Expression for validating Email address

Tags: regex, angular

I want to validate an email id in angular 2 
Now i am using

```
( /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)
```

But if we leave the field empty, it will remain invalid.

so can you suggest me an better option for validating email

Comment: How and where are you using it?

Comment: Refer this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072092/generic-mail-validator-in-angular2

Comment: What's the problem with the solution in this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `|(^$)` at the end of your reg exp to accept empty string:

```
( /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$|(^$)/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
(/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([_\\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)@([0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)[\\.]([a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/)
```

Comment: Why are you limiting TLD to 9 characters? Have a look at http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db  And why haven't you kept the special characters present in OP?