# type ="email" is valid in angular 2?

Tags: angular

`<input type ="email" name="myEmail">`

In anuglar 1 it
 has error and could achive soomthing like this 
( `myForm.myEmail.$error.email`)if it is not correct email id 
but it is not in case of Angular 2 , how to validate it in angular 2  ?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072092/generic-mail-validator-in-angular2

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" [(ngModel)]="notificaion.mail_cc1" name="mail_cc1" maxlength="250" email #cc1='ngModel'>
```

then you can add conditional class or error

```
[ngClass]="{'has-success':(notificationForm.submitted || cc1.dirty) && cc1.valid,
                  'has-error': (notificationForm.submitted || cc1.dirty) && cc1.invalid}"
```