# How do you validate an email field in angular 2 using model driven form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

How do you validate an email field in angular 2 using model driven form, this is what I have so far.

*This is my form component*

```
export class signinComponent {
    signinform: FormGroup;
    constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.signinform = this.fb.group({
           name: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }   
}
```

*This is my form html*

```
<form class="ui form" [formGroup]="signinform" novalidate>
    <div>
        <input type="email" class="emailinput" [formControl]="signinform.controls['email']" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
</form
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072092/generic-mail-validator-in-angular2

Answer (score 2):

Validation method:

```
authEmailValidation( control: FormControl ): {[s:string]:boolean} {
        let pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        if ( !pattern.test( control.value ) ) {
            return { email: true };
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In your component:

```
this.signinform = this.fbuilder.group( {
                    email : ["", [this.authEmailValidation]],
                    // Other fields....
                } );
```

Note: dnt forget in constructor :

```
private signinform : FormGroup;
private fbuilder: FormBuilder 
// and import them
```