# angular2 custom validations and how to import them for my component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want to write a custom validations for my angular2 project. Can you help me, where to write and how to integrate to my components.
I tried like this:

```
function emailValidator(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    alert('---->'+control.value);
  if (!control.value.match(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)) {
    return {invalidEmail: true};
  }
}
```

In console log, it is giving null. Can you help me..
Thanks..

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072092/generic-mail-validator-in-angular2/35477490#35477490

Comment: It is working fine. but when I try to do confirmation password validation, then it is not working. I want to access other fields value also with in my custom validation method. Can you let me know, how to fetch..?
Thanks..