# Validate Email in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

If i want to create a directive which validates my email, how to do it?

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appEmailValidator]'
})

export class EmailValidatorDirective {

  constructor() {}
}
```

Created the directive, but have no idea how to implement validation rules/messages.

Comment: please refr to the answer, and try to implement it. It is better that a custom directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072092/generic-mail-validator-in-angular2

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't need to write your own validator.

Since [**Angular v4.0.0-beta6**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta6-2017-02-03) there's a in-built email validator.

In order to use it, do the following:

```
<input 
  type="email"
  email
  name="emailField" 
  [(ngModel)]="email" 
  #emailField="ngModel">
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UIfwlRyf2rDNOG3FNDx7?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

you can simply achieve it by `pattern` as well. Like:

```
<input 
id="email" 
type="text" 
pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" 
required>
```

Comment: Yeah, I did all that,but I need to do the following somehow, and I am looking for the best solution:

1. Hide validation messages while typing
2. When u type and then delete - show msg: Email required
3. If you type and click outside the input while the email is not valid - msg = Email invalid
4. When u return into the field = hide all previous validation messages

Kind of hard to do for myself :/